# Tiger VNC Wayland Issue

Tags: centos, vnc, wayland

I've more or less setup tiger-vnc with this guide:

https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/centos-install-and-configure-vnc-server/

The problem I'm facing is that when I enable the following, I am unable to keep the session started:

```
sudo systemctl start vncserver@:6001.service
```

It immediately says "active" in the systemctl status, then changed to inactive dead, exited:

```
$ sudo systemctl status vncserver@:6001.service
○ vncserver@:6001.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2022-12-01 19:35:32 GMT; 2s ago
   Duration: 1.265s
    Process: 9262 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/vncsession-restore :6001 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 9273 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/vncsession-start :6001 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 9280 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 19ms
```

When I look through journal-ctl I see:

```
Dec 01 19:35:32 centosstream9 sudo[9364]:    john : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/john ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status vncserver@:6001.service
Dec 01 19:35:31 centosstream9 gnome-session-f[9363]: Cannot open display: 
Dec 01 19:35:31 centosstream9 gnome-session-binary[9307]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Dec 01 19:35:31 centosstream9 gnome-session[9307]: gnome-session-binary[9307]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Dec 01 19:35:31 centosstream9 gnome-session[9357]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: no X11 display found
Dec 01 19:35:31 centosstream9 gnome-session[9352]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: no X11 display found
```

Having checked this server, Centos stream 9, it appears to be using Wayland.  I'm not verify familiar with Wayland, but I know it's supposed to replace X.  So I'm guessing my problem is something to do with that, as to why it's saying the error above (like I'm assuming there's an option somewhere I'm missing to enable wayland support, either that or it's just not compatible).  I'm not actually sure what to do to get this to work, can someone advise?

Comment: I'm far from sure that TigerVNC supports Wayland. You may want to switch back to Xorg.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error and it was caused because the user configured in /etc/tigervnc/vncserver.users was signed into the server already with a graphical session. This is subtly noted at the end of the doc /usr/share/doc/tigervnc/HOWTO.md.